# Using condition with distinct in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Hello everyone I would to ask you a question about using condition in function count with distinct in sql server

`COUNT(DISTINCT CASE E.SEX WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS M`

but result always 1 and 0 it doesn't count up

below is the query

```
SELECT  E.DEPT,D.DESCRIPTION AS DEPARTMENT,JF.CODE,JF.DESCRIPTION AS POSITION,
COUNT(DISTINCT E.EMPCODE) AS ACTUAL,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE E.SEX WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS M,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE E.SEX WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS F,
SUM(CASE WHEN AT.LEAVEDESC = 'ABS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AWP,
SUM(CASE WHEN AT.LEAVEDESC = 'UPL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UPL,
SUM(CASE WHEN AT.LEAVEDESC='DO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DO,
SUM(CASE WHEN AT.LEAVEDESC='AL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AL,
SUM(CASE WHEN AT.LEAVEDESC='PH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PH,
SUM(CASE WHEN AT.LEAVEDESC='MTL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MTL,
SUM(CASE WHEN START1 <> '1900-01-01' AND END1 = '1900-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FCI,
SUM(CASE WHEN START1 = '1900-01-01' AND END1 <> '1900-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FCO
FROM HR_EMPMAST E LEFT JOIN HR_DEPARTMENT D ON E.DEPT = D.CODE 
LEFT JOIN HR_JOBFUNCTION JF ON E.JOBCODE = JF.CODE 
LEFT JOIN AT_EMPSCHEDULE AT ON E.EMPCODE = AT.EMPCODE
WHERE (TERMINATESTATUS = '' OR (DATETERMINATE > N'2/23/2017 8:05:40 AM' AND STARTDATE <= N'2/23/2017 8:05:40 AM')) 
AND AT.TRANDATE BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY E.DEPT,D.DESCRIPTION,JF.CODE,JF.DESCRIPTION
```

![The result that show after run script][10]

Comment: What you are trying to achieve Count(Distinct ) Query? There is only two possibilities for  E.SEX field, That's why it returns 1 or 0

Comment: Because when I JOIN with AT_EMPSCHEDULE it have 28 record for each employee (base on day in month this month Feb=28) but I would like to count employee.

Comment: @Kosal then you should count the `DISTINCT e.empcode` instead of 1 or 0

Comment: And I would like to know how many Female and Male staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the proper count of Male or Female you have to replace 1 with EmpCode, because you are using distinct. hope it helps.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE E.SEX WHEN 'M' THEN E.EMPCODE ELSE NULL END) AS M
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE E.SEX WHEN 'F' THEN E.EMPCODE ELSE NULL END) AS F
```